# Building separate Stylesheets for different themes with webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

Right now we are using a scss mixin ( https://github.com/zellwk/themify ) to provide different themes for our react components in our app.

It works great, but produces rather long selector chains in the compiled css file.

While we do have to provide the ability to change themes during runtime ( which is no hassle with the current solution, we only have to switch one classname on the body element ) the default usecase is, that the theme does not change.

So we thought about reducing the complexity and filesize of our stylesheets by splitting them up in separate files.

Example:

**themes.scss:**

```
$themes: (
  red: (
    mainColor: #aa3939,
    secondaryColor: #D46A6A
  ),
  blue: (
    mainColor: #2e4272,
    secondaryColor: #4f628e
  )
);
```

**button.sccs**

```
@import 'themes.scss';

.button {
  @include themify($themes) {
    color: themed('secondaryColor');  
    background-color: themed('mainColor');  
  }}
}
```

This becomes:

```
.theme-red .button {
  color: #D46A6A;
  background-color: #aa3939;
}

.theme-blue .button {
  color: #4f628e;
  background-color: #2e4272;
}
```

Now I want this to become:

**theme-red.css:**

```
.button {
  color: #D46A6A;
  background-color: #aa3939;
}
```

**theme-blue.css:**

```
.button {
  color: #4f628e;
  background-color: #2e4272;
}
```

We are not depenent on the themify mixin, we could change that to any kind of solution one could make work with webpack. Any hint in the right direction would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this? I'm trying to do something very similar.

Comment: Split up your theme variables in separate 2 entry files. Each entry should only specify the 1 set of theme values it cares about. Your mixin will loop through just that 1 set for each theme entry file you define.

Answer (score 1):

@ManuKaracho, I tried to use the similar approach with the help of these two tutorials and faced the same issue as you are facing.

[Sass Theming: The Neverending Story](https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-theming-neverending-story/)

[Theming Web Apps with SASS](https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1)

The CSS is generated in a single file instead of two separate files. I wanted to generate two separate CSS files just like you. I did some R&D about the issue and finally figured out how to do this.

First of all you need to break your themes.scss file into two separate files as shown below.

**_theme-red-variables.scss**

```
$themes: (
    red: (
      mainColor: #aa3939,
      secondaryColor: #D46A6A
   )
);
```

**_theme-blue-variables.scss**

```
$themes: (
    blue: (
      mainColor: #2e4272,
      secondaryColor: #4f628e
   )
);
```

Next you need to make some changes in your button.scss file. Simply remove the @import statement from the top because we will import theme specific variables into their own separate files as shown below

**button.scss**

```
.button {
    @include themify($themes) {
       color: themed('secondaryColor');  
       background-color: themed('mainColor');  
    }
 }
```

Next you need to create two separate theme files. In these files, you need to import theme specific variables file, mixin file and your button.scss file

**theme-red.scss**

```
// Import red theme variables file
@import 'theme-red-variables';

// Import mixins file, where you have defined themify and themed mixins
@import 'mixins';  

// Import button.scss file in this theme file 
@import 'button';
```

**theme-blue.scss**

```
// Import blue theme variables file
@import 'theme-blue-variables';

// Import mixins file, where you have defined themify and themed mixins
@import 'mixins';  

// Import button.scss file in this theme file 
@import 'button';
```

Two separate files will be generated using the above technique

**theme-red.css**

```
.button {
    color: #D46A6A;
    background-color: #aa3939;
 }
```

**theme-blue.css**

```
.button {
    color: #4f628e;
    background-color: #2e4272;
 }
```

I hope I have explained the solution well and it will help you to resolve your problem.